# Pycharm Language Injection of f-strings

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to get PyCharm to recognise an f-string as an SQL query via the Language Injection feature.

PyCharm doesn't seem to evaluate the f-string and then run the Language Injection test.

Is there anyway to set up PyCharm to evaluate and determine language? I have noticed that if the f-string does not contain any variables then the language injection *does* work.

For example:

`f""" select * from foo where id > 10"""` detects SQL

`f""" select * from foo where id > {id_threshold}"""` does not detect SQL

This also applies for language injection of other languages